# Keep aspect ratio for UIbuttons background image

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

I've been looking for hours and all I find is old answers saying that it cannot be done.

I have a button where I'd like the background image to  be as large as it can be, while keeping its aspect ratio. The background image keeps getting streched no matter what I do. I've tried.

```
    var bluecircle = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "BLUE.png")

    monBreak.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    monBreak.setBackgroundImage(bluecircle, for: UIControlState.normal)
```

Do I really need to make an imageview and put an invisible button over it? That seems like welcoming A LOT of new things that could go wrong.

I tried

```
@IBOutlet weak var monBreak: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var bluecircle = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "BLUE.png")

    let theimagebehindmonBreak = UIImageView(image: bluecircle)
    theimagebehindmonBreak.frame = CGRectFromString( "{{0,0},{40,40}}")
    monBreak.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    monBreak.addSubview(theimagebehindmonBreak)
    theimagebehindmonBreak.image=bluecircle
    theimagebehindmonBreak.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
```

This gets the aspect ratio right, but since I want the layout to be dynamic setting its size to fixed values won't work, plus it's not centered.

At first I tired simply applying the constraints of the button like so

```
    var dacontraints = NSLayoutConstraint(monBreak.constraints)
```

But at this point I get the error "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'NSLayoutConstraint' with an argument list of type '{[NSLayoutconstraints]}'

This is killing me

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a solution where subclassing fits.

Subclass UIButton, add an ImageView in the init, size it to the frame, and set the contentMode properly.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but since I was looking for the same I think this is still valid.

I was trying to do the same (as everyone says) for `backgroundImage` it is impossible. However, if your button will consist of only an icon, then first you should be using the `setImage` method AND if you are using it you'll have access to the `imageView` property of the button. Since this is an UIImageView you can set the `contentMode` to whatever you like.